# How to use addClass() to prepend the class in the element's class list

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I hav a div in my HTML

```
    <button id="abc" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"></button>
```

I need to add a class 'alert-danger' on mouseover. So i used the following code

```
    $(document).on("mouseover","#abc",function()
    {
          $(this).addClass("alert-danger");
    });
```

This works fine and it appends the class at the end of the class list as below

```
    <button id="abc" class="btn btn-primary btn-block alert-danger"></button>
```

But the problem is 'btn' and 'alert-danger' classes have some common css rules. 'btn' takes priority (as it is first in the list) and disables the rules of 'alert-danger'.So my button should be like this with 'alert-danger' class as the first in the classlist.

```
    <button id="abc" class="alert-danger btn btn-primary btn-block"></button> // My requirement
```

How to modify my addClass() in order to prepend the class instead of appending it.

Comment: you can remove all classes with `$(this).removeClass();` and then add all three classes in that specific order `$(this).addClass("alert-danger btn btn-primary btn-block");`

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Wb3G/) as an example for my above suggestion.

Comment: You can also mark !important to css property in alert-danger class, which will prioritize the css effect as per your requirement. Check this updated fiddle of @SamyS.Rathore http://jsfiddle.net/3Wb3G/1/

Comment: @ChiragVidani +1 for mentioning `!important`, personally I prefer CSS solutions over using script for such simple things.

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore Added as an answer

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore your fiddle doesn't work when i added hover property to .btn-primary. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3Wb3G/2/

Comment: @ChiragVidani +1 work's well.. Thank you for help.. :)

Comment: The order of classes has no effect on which get applied first, the definition order in CSS does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to your requirement.

You can mark `!important` to css property in `alert-danger` class, which will prioritize the css effect as per your requirement.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz9nH/) demo.

Excerpt:

```css
.alert-danger{
    background: #FF0000 !important;
    color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your alternative suggestion .. works well :)

Comment: [CSS Reference on `!important`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp)

Comment: “Tip: It is good to know about the !important rule. You might see it in some CSS source code. However, do not use it unless you absolutely have to.”

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
$(document).on("mouseover","#abc",function(){
$(this).removeClass("alert-danger");
$(this).attr("class","alert-danger "+$(this).attr("class"));})
```

Check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLTeq/).

Answer (score -1):

The order of class names in the HTML does not affect the priority or specificity of how the styling is actually applied.